# Need help with python script with bash commands

Tags: python, linux, bash

I copied this script from internet but idon't know how to use it. i am newbiw to python so please help. When i execute it using
./test.py then i can only see

```
usage: py4sa [option]

A unix toolbox

options:
  --version      show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -i, --ip       gets current IP Address
  -u, --usage    gets disk usage of homedir
  -v, --verbose  prints verbosely
```

when i type py4sa then it says bash command not found 
The full script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import optparse
import re

#Create variables out of shell commands
#Note triple quotes can embed Bash

#You could add another bash command here
#HOLDING_SPOT="""fake_command"""

#Determines Home Directory Usage in Gigs
HOMEDIR_USAGE = """
du -sh $HOME | cut -f1
"""

#Determines IP Address
IPADDR = """
/sbin/ifconfig -a | awk '/(cast)/ { print $2 }' | cut -d':' -f2 | head -1
"""

#This function takes Bash commands and returns them
def runBash(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read().strip()
    return out  #This is the stdout from the shell command

VERBOSE=False
def report(output,cmdtype="UNIX COMMAND:"):
   #Notice the global statement allows input from outside of function
   if VERBOSE:
       print "%s: %s" % (cmdtype, output)
   else:
       print output

#Function to control option parsing in Python
def controller():
    global VERBOSE
    #Create instance of OptionParser Module, included in Standard Library
    p = optparse.OptionParser(description='A unix toolbox',
                                            prog='py4sa',
                                            version='py4sa 0.1',
                                            usage= '%prog [option]')
    p.add_option('--ip','-i', action="store_true", help='gets current IP Address')
    p.add_option('--usage', '-u', action="store_true", help='gets disk usage of homedir')
    p.add_option('--verbose', '-v',
                action = 'store_true',
                help='prints verbosely',
                default=False)

    #Option Handling passes correct parameter to runBash
    options, arguments = p.parse_args()
    if options.verbose:
        VERBOSE=True
    if options.ip:
        value = runBash(IPADDR)
        report(value,"IPADDR")
    elif options.usage:
        value = runBash(HOMEDIR_USAGE)
        report(value, "HOMEDIR_USAGE")
    else:
        p.print_help()

#Runs all the functions
def main():
    controller()

#This idiom means the below code only runs when executed from command line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you have stored the script under another name: test.py rather than py4sa. So typing ./test.py, like you did, is correct for you. The program requires arguments, however, so you have to enter one of the options listed under 'usage'.

Normally 'py4sa [OPTIONS]' would mean that OPTIONS is optional, but looking at the code we can see that it isn't:

```
if options.verbose:
    # ...
if options.ip:
    # ...
elif options.usage:
    # ...
else:
    # Here's a "catch all" in case no options are supplied. 
    # It will show the help text you get:
    p.print_help()
```

Note that the program probably would not be recognized by bash even if you renamed it to py4sa, as the current directory is often not in bash's PATH. It says 'usage: py4sa (..)' because that's hard-coded into the program.

Answer (score 0):

The script is called "test.py". Either invoke it as such, or rename it to "py4sa".

Answer (score 0):

you run a Python script using the interpreter, so

`$ python py4sa`